# InApp Purchase content compatibility on multiple mobile platforms (iOS and Android.)

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, compatibility

I have one application developed in both platform, where multiple users see each other online when they are using apps at same time.

User A using iPhone can see User B using android within same application.

Now I want to add one more feature of gifting each other based on certain occasions.

So, is it possible to purchase digital content (eg- smiley icons, cards, etc) via in app purchase process of iPhone application and then gift it to User B who is actually using Android version of application?

Inverse should also be case, where User B (android) purchase digital content and send it to User A(iPhone).

Note: I Know that in-app purchase with in same platform is not a problem, it means if all users are using iPhone or Android then it is not a problem. But in my case I have two different platform.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, no, you cannot cross-buy items between iOS and Android. However another approach is that you implement the possibillity to buy "credits" in both Android/iOS stores. Then implement and host your own DRM-service, where your users could use/give away credits.

Answer (score 5):

Speaking about the iOS In App purchase and following the [App Store Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies):

> Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to
>   purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be
>   rejected

This means that you can't purchase somethings on android and than unlock something on iOS

> Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used
>   outside of the application will be rejected

And this means that you can't purchase something in iOS and use it on Android.

Comment: 'This means that you can't purchase somethings on android and than unlock something on iOS' 
Feature what i have to develop has nothing to do with unlocking content which exist in application. it is something you on android purchase one good photo of sunset and gift to me on iphohe. so when you gift it is sent as file from server to me on iphone. so iphone user does not know weather it is purchased content, he just know that he get good photo to see.
So i think it should work because i am not purchasing any physical good and also i am not using purchased content outside then app.

Answer (score 4):

One simple solution is to keep the trace of what is bought on your server that is queried by both Android & iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Teovald is right, I had to do a test with a dating app that is available on iOS and Android, I bought a one month suscription via iTunes and then my one month suscription was also available on Android app too.

Thanks for all your input with this.

Regards
Antonio

Comment: Does the cross-platform server side implementation only work for subscription-based purchases? Or does it also work for non-consumable or consumable purchases as well?